# Could you have a hard drive imaging option in Grub?

Tags: grub, disk-image

I really like HD imaging programs, such as Norton Ghost, but I find that I don't run then as often as I should.

Would it be possible to have, in Grub, the following menu items: ?

- Boot from hard disk
- Copy hard disk to image
- Restore image

Comment: This is a brilliant idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes.

one of the many ways of doing it would be to set up a small partition containing Clonezilla and create a grub menu entry for booting into that.  Clonezilla will give you the disk/partition imaging tools you want.

Comment: Yeeeeeeeah that's ok, but I was looking for something with least amount of user input. In clonezilla, I would have to select the partition I want to save, and the file I want to save it in, worrying that I've picked the wrong file or partition.. If I always copy the same partition to the same file, I'd like to be able to do it automaticly. But your answer could be an alternate solution, yes.

Comment: if you mostly want to repeat the same image save/restore operations, then this might help - clonezilla will tell you what command it is about to execute so you can run it directly from the command line rather than by navigating the menus.  you could cut and paste them (one for save, one for restore) into scripts and then add options to the clonezilla main menu.